# ‎Is the functional sequence ‎$f_n(x)$ ‎uniformly ‎convergent‎ ‎on ‎$‎[1, 2]‎$‎?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the functional sequence
‎‎\begin{align*}‎
‎f_n(x) = ‎\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n+2} + \sum_{k=1}^n ‎\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+x+2}} - ‎‎‎‎\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+x+1}}, (1\leq x\leq 2, n=1,2,3,...).
‎‎\end{align*}‎‎‎
Is ‎$‎f_n(x)‎$ ‎uniformly ‎convergent ‎on ‎‎$‎[1, 2]‎$?‎
‎

‎ I‎ ‎know ‎that ‎‎$f(x) =‎ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{k+x+2}‎} - ‎‎‎‎‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{k+x+1}‎}‎ = ‎‎‎‎\frac{-1}{2‎\sqrt{x+2}‎}‎‎‎$,‎
but I do not know how to use the supremm test‎. ‎Please ‎guide ‎me?‎
(Let ‎$‎M_n = sup|f_n(x) - f(x)|‎$‎, so ‎$‎f_n‎‎\rightarrow ‎f‎$ ‎is ‎uniformly ‎convergent ‎on ‎‎$‎E‎$ ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if ‎‎$‎M_n‎‎\rightarrow ‎0‎$ ‎as ‎‎$‎n‎‎\rightarrow ‎\infty‎$‎)‎.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in[1,2]$,
$$
\begin{align}‎
‎f_n(x)
&=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{k+x+2}}-\frac1{2\sqrt{k+x+1}}\right)\\
&=-\underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}}}_{\le\frac1{2\sqrt{n+1}}}+\underbrace{\frac1{2\sqrt{x+n+2}}}_{\le\frac1{2\sqrt{n+3}}}-\frac1{2\sqrt{x+2}}\\
‎‎\end{align}
$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: robjohn. Thanks. ‎$‎M_n = sup|f_n(x) - f(x)| = sup|‎\frac{-1}{‎\sqrt{n+1} + ‎\sqrt{n+2}‎} + ‎‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{n+x+2}‎} - ‎‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{x+2}‎}‎ + \ ‎‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{x+2}‎}|‎\leq ‎‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{n+1}‎}+‎\frac{1}{‎\sqrt{n+3}‎}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$, since‎ ‎‎‎$‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(‎‎\frac{1}{2‎\sqrt{n+1}‎}+‎\frac{1}{‎\sqrt{n+3}‎}) = 0‎$‎  ‎as ‎‎$‎n‎‎\rightarrow ‎\infty‎$‎, so  ‎‎$‎M_n‎‎\rightarrow ‎0‎$. ‎I‎s it right?

Comment: @koohyareslami: yes. The important point is that there is no dependence on $x$ in $\sup|f_n-f|$.